# Combining angular-ui progressbar with ngClass

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, ng-class

I would like to combine the directive progress from angular-ui, with the directive ngClass.

So far I don't get any reactions at all. Am I doing this wrong, or is it not possible to combine?

What I want is a progressbar that has the class active when the background process is working, but turns off when it's complete or errnous.

HTML:

```
<progress max="100" percent="progress" class='progress-striped' 
    ng-class='{"active": active}'></progress>
```

JS:

```
$scope.active = true;
$scope.progress = {value:10, type:"danger"};
```

See my plunkr at http://plnkr.co/edit/koR0VnTKdpnhhMuD16hl

Cheers!

Comment: To clarify, the class .active is set onto progressbar so it animates a scrolling effect. Updated plunkr to reflect this.

Comment: See my edit, seems it works like you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you also  to try `ng-style`. Your problem is solved here

```
<div class="container_progress">
     <div class="progress progress-striped"   ng-class='{"active": active, "":!active}'>
       <div  class="bar" ng-style="bar_upload_style" >{{bar_upload_text}}</div>  
     </div>
</div>
```

And in controller:

```
updateProgressBar(20);

 $timeout(function()
 {
 updateProgressBar(100);
 }, 4000);


function updateProgressBar(value){
 $scope.bar_upload_style = {  "width": value+'%'  };
 $scope.bar_upload_text = value + "%";

 if(value ==100) $scope.active = false;
}
```

See <kbd>**[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/53z0REpXbBSgtiNM4g9L?p=preview)**</kbd>

In my case I took progress bar from bootstrap as is and changed `%`

Comment: This solution works. It's not pretty though :o

I'll try to find a solution where angular-ui-bootstrap is still used. I thought that I could add a ng-class-directive inside the template for the progress directive. It would be neat to push it to their github in the end.

A problem that arises when copy-pasting it out like this is that all the functionality of the progress directive is lost. But maybe this is not a problem, the progress directive is not that extensive right now.

Comment: please, let me know if you will find solution

Comment: I haven't tried that much other things, but in the end, this worked perfectly, with some changes. just using ng-class='{"active: active}' on the first div, and then ng-class='{"bar-danger": danger, "bar-success": success}' on the innerdiv. I figure one could do ng-class='{"bar-danger": statusClass=="danger", "bar-success": statusClass="success"}' as well.

Sadly, this means that all features of the angular-ui-bootstrap are gone. But it works out ok in my case.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Angular UI rewrite the DOM to replace `<progress>` tag with `<div>`.
It appears than in this process `ng-class` is omitted.

You can resolve your problem by wrapping your progress bar in another `<div>` and add your `ng-class` directive on this element. After you can add styles on `.active .progress`.

HTML :

```
<div ng-class='{"active": active}'>
    <progress max="100" percent="progress" class='progress-striped'></progress> 
</div>
```

CSS :

```
.active .progress {
    /* Put your styles here */
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I updated the plunkr to reflect what happens if I add the active class to the progress, I assume it would be possible to achieve with this solution as well?